# Write list of lists to csv row

Tags: python, python-3.3

How would I print each list in list1 or list2 as a column without the '[ ]' included?

```
import csv
def test():
    list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 5], [9, 3, 6, 8, 4]]
    list2 = [[2, 2, 4, 4], [1, 9, 10], [2, 7, 7, 4, 5]]
    with open('doc.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(list1)
        writer.writerow(list2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

This is close to what I desire but has [ ] in the string:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4],[3, 2, 5],[9, 3, 6, 8, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 4],[1, 9, 10],[2, 7, 7, 4, 5]
```

EDIT:

I want:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4","3, 2, 5","9, 3, 6, 8, 4"
"2, 2, 4, 4","1, 9, 10","2, 7, 7, 4, 5"
```

Comment: What do you want each list-in-a-column to look like?

Comment: Please show the output you _actually_ desire, instead of just showing us the incorrect output and making us guess what you might want instead.

Comment: Your edit is a very weird CSV. The columns in the first row are `1`, `2`, `3`, `4    3`, `2`, etc. Is that really what you want? (In particular, besides the flattening, that column with a `4`, four spaces, and a `3` doesn't look very useful…)

Comment: @abarnert: added quotes around them to make it more clear

Comment: @user1991424: In the future, show _exactly_ the output you're getting and _exactly_ the output you desire; it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: @abarnert: my aplogies, i thought i was just making it clear that I wanted them each as a separate column. I will keep you advice in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
import csv

def nested_list_formatter(nested):
    return tuple(','.join(str(item) for item in sublist) for sublist in nested)

def test():
    list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 5], [9, 3, 6, 8, 4]]
    list2 = [[2, 2, 4, 4], [1, 9, 10], [2, 7, 7, 4, 5]]
    with open('doc.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(nested_list_formatter(list1))
        writer.writerow(nested_list_formatter(list2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Resulting contents of`doc.csv`:

```
"1,2,3,4","3,2,5","9,3,6,8,4"
"2,2,4,4","1,9,10","2,7,7,4,5"
```

Answer (score 1):

A column is just printed by calling `str` on it. So, if you want to do something else, you have to convert each column into a string yourself* (since calling `str` on a string just returns the string).

In your case, we have to turn every element of the outer list into strings in the format we want… which will itself require turning every element of each inner list into strings so we can join them up in some way. In general, in Python, to do something to every element of a sequence, you either call `map`, or you write a comprehension, so I'll do one of each.

After your edits, it looks like you want comma-separated columns, and comma-space-separated values within the columns, but that's OK because you want the columns auto-quoted. That's easy.

To join up the values with `', '`, you just call `', '.join()` on them.

```
def stringify_column_list(column_list):
    return ', '.join(str(value) for value in column_list)
```

The weird separator and quoting, you already know how to handle in the `writer`. So the only thing left is to call our formatting function on each column:

```
writer.writerow(map(stringify_column_list, list1))
writer.writerow(map(stringify_column_list, list2))
```

---

You might even want to consider using the `csv` module again to create the column values. But this is probably overkill here.

---

* Or into some other object with a `__str__` method that does what you want, but that's rarely worth doing.

Comment: Doesnt the csv.QUOTE_ALL take care of the comma separators?

Comment: @user1991424: Well, I didn't put too much stock in the `writer` you actually wrote, because you clearly aren't going to get columns separated by 4 spaces (as you seem to want) when you let it default to commas as the separator.

Comment: The spaces are to show the distinction between columns. I will fix my post

Comment: @user1991424: Rather than going back and forth 30 more times… Does my answer show you how to do what you want, or do you still not get it and need help with something?

Comment: getting `_csv.Error: sequence expected`

Comment: @user1991424: What's your code, what's your input, and what's the traceback? Without that information, all I can say is that you're calling `writerow` with a single value instead of a sequence of values (or `writerows` with a single sequence instead of a sequence of sequences).